# How to rewrite this query without temporary table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written the following query using temporary tables. However, I am not sure how to write this without temp tables. Subqueries are allowed.

Below is the query that I wrote using temporary tables. I need to write it using a

subquery (not using temporary tables) but cannot seem to get it working. I have also uploaded my best attempt at writing a subquery. I read online that the update table cannot be in the subquery so I am not sure how to go about that. Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks!

My query with temporary tables

```sql
SET  @frequency=4;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test.detailsfirstname;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test.detailsfirstname (
   contact_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
   first_name VARCHAR(100),
   c_first_name VARCHAR(100),
   PRIMARY KEY (`contact_id`));
INSERT IGNORE INTO test.detailsfirstname
(
   contact_id,
   first_name,
   c_first_name
)
   SELECT
      cd.contact_id,
      TRIM(c.first_names) AS `first_name`,
      IFNULL(cd.first_name,' ') AS `c_first_name`
   FROM
      production.contact_d cd
      JOIN abc.contacts c ON(cd.contact_id=c.contact_id)
   WHERE
      1=1
      AND ((c.last_modified_at<=NOW() AND c.last_modified_at>= NOW() - INTERVAL @frequency HOUR))
      OR cd.first_name IS NULL
   HAVING
      `first_name`<>`c_first_name`;

UPDATE production.contact_d p1,(
   SELECT
      contact_id,
      first_name
   FROM
      test.detailsfirstname
                                                  ) AS p2
   SET
      p1.first_name=p2.first_name
   WHERE
      p1.contact_id=p2.contact_id;
```

My attempt at using a subquery

```
    SET  @frequency=4;

UPDATE IGNORE production.contact_d p1,(
   SELECT
      contact_id,
      first_name
   FROM
      (
      
      SELECT
      cd.contact_id,
      TRIM(c.first_names) AS `first_name`,
      IFNULL(cd.first_name,' ') AS `c_first_name`
   FROM
      production.contact_d cd
      JOIN abc.contacts c ON(cd.contact_id=c.contact_id)
   WHERE
      1=1
      AND ((c.last_modified_at<=NOW() AND c.last_modified_at>= NOW() - INTERVAL @frequency HOUR))
      OR cd.first_name IS NULL
   HAVING
      `first_name`<>`c_first_name`;
      
      )) AS p2
   SET
      p1.first_name=p2.first_name
   WHERE
      p1.contact_id=p2.contact_id;
```

Comment: MySQL (version?) or SQL-Server… which is it?

Comment: Considering the use of backticks (`\``) for delimit identifying, along with other syntax (such as `INT(11)`) I've taken the liberty of assuming MySQL. If you are using SQL Server you would get an error in the above, as (for the 2 reasons I listed) T-SQL uses brackets (`[]`) and `int` does not have a precision property.

Comment: Can you please change your query to the smallest, albeit artificial, query that demonstrates the problem/complexity you’re facing? See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks for formatting it and the tips. I am using MySQL 8.0.

Comment: How many different values can `@frequency` have?

Comment: @Bohemian only 1 value.

Comment: @Bohemian, so in theory I think I can get rid of the "SET..." clause and just hardcode the value of 4 in the code.

Comment: If @frequency is always 4, why is it stored in a variable?

Comment: @Larnu, MySQL does not have an integer precision property either. The argument to the int type is a display hint only. It has no effect on precision or size of the integer.

Comment: That may be, but `int(11)` in T-SQL would error, @BillKarwin , it doesn't support precision declaration at all, hint or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you eradicate the `@frequency` variable and code its value `4` instead, you can create a `view` instead:

```
create view test.detailsfirstname as
SELECT
  cd.contact_id,
  TRIM(c.first_names) AS `first_name`,
  IFNULL(cd.first_name,' ') AS `c_first_name`
FROM production.contact_d cd
JOIN abc.contacts c ON(cd.contact_id=c.contact_id)
WHERE 1=1
AND ((c.last_modified_at<=NOW() AND c.last_modified_at>= NOW() - INTERVAL 4 HOUR))
  OR cd.first_name IS NULL
HAVING `first_name`<>`c_first_name`
```

Then use it exactly like you would your temporary table.

Comment: thanks! really appreciate your help. So, if lets say the @frequency was not constant would the view not work?

Comment: Create different views for each frequency. I would include the frequency in the name for example `detailsfirstname_4_hours`. If the practical range of values frequency can take is modest, such an approach is manageable. Or if it change permanently (rather than varies from time to time), redefine the view with `create or replace view …`